# How to remove height setting on VC Image Carousel in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

[image: I've colored the empty space and underlined the inline CSS both in red]
I'm using Ecode theme from Themeforest with Wordpress 4.9.10. On mobile browsers the VC image carousel is adding an inline height on each of the slides (div.vc_item) which leaves a large white space under the carousel. I've looked at the PHP and js files and don't see where this is being added, but I'm also not very experienced with js.

I can override the inline CSS by using .vc_item{height:unset !important} but there's a delay when the page loads you see the gap for about 1-2 seconds before the stylesheet applies. It also doesn't appear to work at all for Safari on iOS devices.

I also tried changing the element in

> js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_images_carousel.php

from
`<div class="vc_item">`
to
`<div class="vc_item" style="height:unset !important">` but the js just overwrites it (I expected as much but was desperate).

Can anyone point me in the right direction to remove or fix this errant javascript? I haven't even been able to determine where the js is coming from to begin troubleshooting it.

Update: So I've discovered something interesting. The inline height setting is equal to the width of the image. No matter what size image I use it always sets the height of the div equal to the width of the image. Still have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been caused by a bug with the Litespeed cache plugin. After disabling and re-enabling said plugin the issue resolved itself.